# vue-jest error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" caused by `import PictureInput from 'vue-picture-input'`

Tags: vue.js, webpack, jestjs

I'm new to Jest and `vue-jest`. Just trying to get basic tests working.

In my `bootstrap.js` file (this file will, ideally, be loaded for all tests), I attempt to register the 3rd party component `vue-picture-input`:

```
import PictureInput from 'vue-picture-input';
Vue.component('picture-input', PictureInput);
```

(This is part of a standard file (`bootstrap.js`) file I use for my entire project.) But Jest gives me the following error:

```
Details:

/home/vagrant/Code/Patrol/node_modules/vue-picture-input/PictureInput.vue:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){<template>
                                                                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

  85 | // ...
  86 | 
> 87 | import PictureInput from 'vue-picture-input';
     | ^
  88 | Vue.component('picture-input', PictureInput);
```

I've taken a look at similar questions on Stack Overflow for this error, but I can't seem to decipher what is going on or what I need to change. Seems like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558029/1071874) addresses a similar issue, but I don't know how to adapt the solution for this particular issue (or if it's even close, to be honest).

Currently, the "jest" section of my `package.json` file reads:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(css|scss|sass|less)$": "<rootDir>/tests/js/config/cssLoader.js"
  },
  "transform": {
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
  }
}
```

Not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 1):

Update: Found the [solution on Github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest/issues/41).

The solution was to add the following snippet to `package.json` in the `"jest"` section:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!vue-picture-input)"
]
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was just getting this error because I accidentally put a `.` on the beginning of my `jest.config.js` file, so Jest was forgetting the `transform` mappings:

```
transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
},'
```

In this case, the config file wasn't registered properly but did exist.