# Using html-loader with angularJS (v1) templates and Jest is failing

Tags: angularjs, webpack, jestjs, webpack-html-loader

I've got an AngularJS (v.1.7) app served by Rails.  I just moved from Sprockets to Webpack.
While trying to migrate my Jasmine tests to Jest.  I ran into an issue with `html-loader` which I'm using to import my directive templates into the directive.

For one simple directive where I import the template, Jest fails to load the test because the `html-loader` fails with the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

      1 | const htmlLoader = require("html-loader");
      2 | module.exports = {
    > 3 |   process: (src) => htmlLoader(src)
        |                     ^
      4 | };
      5 |
    at getOptions (node_modules/html-loader/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/getOptions.js:6:31)
```

I was following recommendations [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483893/how-can-i-use-my-webpacks-html-loader-imports-in-jest-tests) and from [this npm package html-loader-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader-jest).  In my `package.json`, I've added the following `jest` config

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "html"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.html$": "<rootDir>/jest/support/html_loader.js"
    },
    ...
  }
```

And the support file

```js
// jest/support/html_loader.js
const htmlLoader = require("html-loader");
module.exports = {
  process: (src) => htmlLoader(src) 
};
```

The stacktrace points me to `html-loader` (from node_modules)

```js
// node_modules/html-loader/node_modules/loader-utils/lib/getOptions.js
function getOptions(loaderContext) {
  const query = loaderContext.query;
...
```

If I trace into here during the Jest run, I find this `loaderContext` undefined (as the error reports).

My question is... is this the correct way to use this `htmlLoader`?  If so, what should I expect `loaderContext` to be?  Is there a way to get jest to provide that value?  Or is this not the way the `htmlLoader` is supposed to be called outside of the actual Webpack pipeline.

This problem only happens when I'm running via `jest`.  `webpack` properly compiles the all assets for the app.

#### library versions

```
html-loader: 1.0.0
webpack: 4.42.1
jest: 25.2.4
```

#### code (for clarity)

```js
// mailer.js
import angular from "angular";
import ngInject from "@js/ng-inject";
import template from "./index.html";

const mailer = ngInject(function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      text: "@",
    },
    template: template,
  };
});
angular.module("app-directives").directive("mailer", mailer);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<a>{{text}}</a>
```

```js
// mailer.test.js
import expect from "expect";
import "./mailer";

describe("app-directives.mailer", function () {
  it("works", () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  It seems that when `jest` runs, it's not passing the correct context (as I suspected above) causing the `getOptions` call to fail.

The solution was to write a very simple loader just for `jest` which does not bother with `getOptions`.  I was able to replace my `jest/support/html_loader.js` code with the following (basically cribbed from [`webpack-contrib/raw-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader/blob/master/src/index.js).

```js
// jest/support/html-loader.js
module.exports = {
  process: (content, _path) => {
    // escape newlines
    const json = JSON.stringify(content)
          .replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028')
          .replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029');
    return `module.exports = ${json};`
  }
};
```

This basically returns the template as js module that exports the template.  The `replace` appears to be dealing with newlines.

I hope this saves someone else some digging.