# Jest unit test error: failed to load HTML component template

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jestjs

My Jest unit tests fails to load the HTML template for my Angular app component.

The error is

> Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load app.component.html`

**Note:** That happened while upgrading various dependencies of our code repository except for the Angular.JS application. This is why I'm wondering why the unit tests worked fine before and are failing now.

I double checked that the path to `app.component.html` is correct and that there are no unhandled asynchronous operations in my unit tests. The dependencies are alsocompatible with Angular 12 and Jest.

I have also tried this idea https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/301. However the custom tsconfig is not anymore available.

Then I tested [Cannot run Jest tests for components (Failed to load html files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69863320/cannot-run-jest-tests-for-components-failed-to-load-html-files), but ran into the very same error.

Here's the code. Hopefully anyone has an idea how to fix that. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

The Angular HTML component code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './reusable/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
}
```

The code for the unit test:

```
import { waitForAsync, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './reusable/services/auth.service';
import { mockAuthService } from '../test/mocks/mock.auth.service';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule],
        declarations: [AppComponent],
        providers: [
          {
            provide: AuthService,
            useValue: mockAuthService,
          },
        ],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The Jest config:

```
require('jest-preset-angular/ngcc-jest-processor');
const {pathsToModuleNameMapper} = require('ts-jest/utils');
const {paths} = require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions;
const {defaults} = require('jest-preset-angular/presets');
const esModules = ['@angular'];
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ...pathsToModuleNameMapper(paths, {prefix: '<rootDir>'}),
    '^lodash-es$': 'lodash',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html|svg)?$': 'jest-preset-angular',
  },
  rootDir: '.',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      ...defaults.globals['ts-jest'],
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
    },
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    `<rootDir>/node_modules/.pnpm/(?!.*\\.mjs$|${esModules.join('|')})`
  ],
};
```

The typescript tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "src/*" : ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "disableTypeScriptVersionCheck": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

The dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "12.2.7",
    "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "1.22.2",
    "@briebug/jest-schematic": "3.1.0",
    "@ungap/structured-clone": "1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.2",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "date-fns": "2.28.0",
    "ng2-charts": "2.4.3",
    "ng2-date-picker": "9.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "14.3.0",
    "pretty-format": "27.5.1",
    "rxjs": "7.4.0",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "12.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/cli": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.2.7",
    "@types/chart.js": "2.9.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.10",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.2",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@types/ungap__structured-clone": "0.3.0",
    "html-loader": "3.1.2",
    "canvas": "2.9.3",
    "concurrently": "6.2.2",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "gts": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "jest": "27.2.4",
    "jest-diff": "27.5.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "10.0.1",
    "json-server": "0.16.3",
    "pkg-dir-cli": "2.1.0",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  }
```